# Looking for solution to array and cout interaction in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, cout

I want a function or loop to run through the array and print each element out until it has printed 10 elements.         In which case, a new line is started and the printing continues. eg. 1 2 3 4 5
                                6 7 8 9 10

This is for a program that works an array like a 50's housewife performing many calculations and alterations to said array.

This is my current attack on the logic behind my issue.

```
int main()
    {
test = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){                      
//Set array to rand
            test[i] = rand() % 44 + 55;
        }

        printf("original List\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){          
// print original order
            printf("%d\n", test[i]);
        }


        sortArr;                
// function call sort array ascend

        printf("\Sorted List\n");
            for (int i = 0;i < 100;i++) {           
// print sorted order

                printf("%d , ", test[i]);
                int temp;
//temp counter for width of printout

for (temp = 0;temp < 10;temp++) cout<< "\n" << endl;


sum += test[i];

            }
```

Expected is a block of output consisting of 100 array elements in a grid with a width of 10 elements per line.

Actual result is a mess of new line loops and further headache to me.

Comment: Well, what exactly did you expect from a `for` loop that runs ten times, and prints a newline each time in the loop, followed by another newline (from `std::endl`)? If you expected anything other than twenty newlines in a row, can you explain why you expected something other than the plain result of this very simple for-loop? What you want is just one newline after every 10th element. You happen to already be using `i` to count each element, as it gets printed, so just add a newline every ten `i`s.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Please be nice?

Comment: I expected a newline after 10 counts of the for loop, but seem to understand what you're saying about problems with the newlines being exponential because of it.

Comment: You are printing a newline followed by `std::endl` in a loop that does nothing else. The end result from that, of course, would be twenty newlines in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty common issue just use a modulus based on the index i:

```
for (int i = 0;i < 100;i++) {           
    printf("%d , ", test[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0) {
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If you want nicely formatted output however you'll need:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

and

```
std::cout << std::setw(/*max_len*/) << test[i];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll have to remember that if statement with modulus index. Super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to print the delimiter `(i%10 == 0) ? "\n" : ", "`.  You correctly recognized that taking the remainder on every iteration of the loop is inefficient, and wanted to write one that would print ten elements followed by a newline.

The trick there is to write an inner loop that increments a second counter, `j`, do all your output within the inner loop, and then update `i` at the bottom of the outer loop.  A simplified example:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
  constexpr size_t ARRAY_LEN = 100;
  std::array<int, ARRAY_LEN> test;

  {
    // Quick and dirty initialization of the random seed to the lowest 30
    // or so bits of the system clock, which probably does not really have
    // nanosecond precision.  It’ll do for this purpose.

    timespec current_time;
    timespec_get( &current_time, TIME_UTC );
    srand(current_time.tv_nsec);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++){
    //Set array to rand
    test[i] = rand() % 44 + 55;
  }

  for ( int i = 0, j = 0;
        i < test.size();
        i += j ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < 10 && i + j < test.size(); ++j ) {
      cout << test[i + j] << ' ';
    }

    cout << '\n';
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that the version you wrote does not initialize the standard library’s random seed, so you get the same (poorly-distributed) random numbers.  You could write a version that uses the much superior STL random-number generators and perhaps `<chrono>`, instead of the C versions, but that’s a bit outside the scope of your question.